# Как масштабировать один из двух объектов?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Необходимо масштабировать только Сферу а Цилиндр оставить как есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется Цилиндр и сфера.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "gl/glut.h"   //Подключение библиотеки glut.h
#include "gl/glaux.h"

using namespace std;

int angle = 15;

void initialize() 
{
    /* Обозначаем цвет фона */
    glClearColor(0.1, 1.0, 0.6, 1.0);

    /* Указываем тип матрицы */
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    /* Загружаем тип матрицы и фон */
    glLoadIdentity();
    /* Потом устанавливаем диапазон изменения координат */
    glOrtho(-200.0, 200.0, -200.0, 200.0, -200.0, 200.0);
}
void DrawCylinder() {
    glPushMatrix(); //Сохраняем текущие координаты
    GLUquadricObj *cylinder;
    cylinder = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gluCylinder(cylinder, 15, 15, 40, 16, 16);
    glPopMatrix();
}
//каркасная сфера
void DrawSphere()
{
    glPushMatrix();

    GLUquadricObj *sphere;
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(sphere, GLU_LINE);
    //Красный
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 20.0);
    gluSphere(sphere, 18.0, 16, 16);

    //glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    //glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Выбираем белый цвет
    //glutWireSphere(0.20, 16, 16); //Отображает каркасную сферу GLUT
    //отодвигаем на 40....
    //  glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, z);
    //glScalef(z, z, z

    glScalef(2, 2, 2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPopMatrix();
}
void display() 
{
    /* Очищаем экран */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    DrawCylinder();
    DrawSphere();
    glPopMatrix();
    /* Обновляем экран */
    glFlush();
}
void KeyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'Z':
            //z = z + 0.1;
            //cout << "Увеличиваем всё на(Z)- " << z << endl;
            break;
        case 'z':
            //z = z - 0.1;
            //cout << "Уменьшаем всё на(z)- " << z << endl;
            break;
        case '1':
            cout << "сдвиг влево" << endl;
            glTranslatef(-0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "сдвиг вправо" << endl;
            glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "сдвиг вверх" << endl;
            glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "сдвиг вниз" << endl;
            glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.2f, 0.0f);
            break;
        case '5':
            cout << "вращать влево" << endl;
            glRotatef(-angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            break;
        case '6':
            cout << "вращать вправо" << endl;
            glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            break;
        case '7':
            cout << "вращать вверх" << endl;
            glRotatef(angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            break;
        case '8':
            cout << "вращать вниз" << endl;
            glRotatef(-angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            break;
    }
    cout << "Нажали = " << key << endl;
    display();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);



    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 750);       //Указываем размер окна

    glutInitWindowPosition(680, 20);    //Позиция окна

    glutCreateWindow("Первая лаба");        //Имя окна

    initialize();                       //Вызов функции Initialize

    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPress);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);    //Вызов функции отрисовки

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересное у вас имя окошка "Первая лаба", лето же какие лабы :)

Comment: @Unick закрытие долгов О_о

Comment: Старью какому-то учат на этих лабах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенесите масштабирование `glScalef(2, 2, 2);` **до** вызова отрисовки сферы `gluSphere(sphere, 18.0, 16, 16);`. Тогда и получится.

А то сейчас вы сначала отрисовали, потом ввели масштаб (а он действует только на то что будет нарисовано после), тут же его сбросили `glLoadIdentity();` да еще и матрицу откатили `glPopMatrix();`.